# How to delete specific table partition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2022

I am able to switch out and IN and also truncate partition.But I am not able to delete specific partition file in SQL Server. Suppose there is total 4 partition in order table, I don't need partition 1 where data of 2016 . How can I do it? Is it possible to delete those ndf partition file.

```
table_name  partition_range         file_groupName  partition_number    number_of_rows
Orders      NULL                    PRIMARY           4                 600956
Orders      2016-12-31 00:00:00.000 orders_2016       1                 200988
Orders      2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 orders_2017       2                 99694
Orders      2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 orders_2018       3                 99334
```

I have deleted partition using below steps, but not sure whether it is actual process or not:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Orders  WITH (PARTITIONS (1));
```

Alter partition schema which is already created

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME order_by_year_schema NEXT USED orders_2017;
```

Used to eliminate a boundary point and thus merge the ranges of two partitions.

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION order_by_year_function() MERGE RANGE ('2016-12-31');
```

This command moves all data from the specified file to other files.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('orders_2016', EMPTYFILE);
```

REMOVE database file

```
ALTER DATABASE orders REMOVE FILE orders_2023;
```

REMOVE database filegroup

```
ALTER DATABASE orders REMOVE FILEGROUP orders_2023;
```

Need expert opinion and also guide me on this if I am not correct. Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830744/drop-empty-partition-objects-after-truncate-partition